# Terraform User_Data For Autoscaling Not Running

Tags: terraform

I require assistance to understand how to create data to put a bash script in it. I have a dynamic IP address and it doesn't work if I use the file or base64 echo.

```
data "template_file" "test" {
  base64_encode = true
  template = <<-EOT
# Define the path to the sshd_config file
sshd_config="/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

# Define the string to be replaced
old_string="PasswordAuthentication no"
new_string="PasswordAuthentication yes"

# Check if the file exists
if [ -e "$sshd_config" ]; then
    # Use sed to replace the old string with the new string
    sudo sed -i "s/$old_string/$new_string/" "$sshd_config"

    # Check if the sed command was successful
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "String replaced successfully."
        # Restart the SSH service to apply the changes
        sudo service ssh restart
    else
        echo "Error replacing string in $sshd_config."
    fi
else
    echo "File $sshd_config not found."
fi

echo "123" | passwd --stdin ec2-user
systemctl restart sshd
  EOT
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "terraform-template-app" {
  name_prefix            = "terraform-template-app-"
  image_id               = "ami-018ba43095ff50d08"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.terraform-public-facing-sg-app.id
  ]
  user_data = base64encode(data.template_file.test.rendered)
  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags = {
      Name = "myasg"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see the script being run in /var/log/message or var/log/cloud-init-output.log

Comment: What does "nothing is running in cloud-init.log" mean?

Comment: I meant after I run terraform apply. I think it skip the script in user_data

Comment: So not even the echo where you want to show the error is there?

Comment: Yes. The script isn't running not even hello world

Comment: Do you see the code in the instance?

Comment: Looks like the AWS console has changed a bit (at least since I visited last)... once you have the instance selected the user data is under: [Actions] > [Instance settings] > [Edit user data] ... if yours is not there then we have to look at the output of a terraform plan see what it shows for `user_data`

Comment: Try add `!#/bin/bash` as the first line of the user date file.

Comment: Also I see you are base64 encoding twice, once with `base64_encode = true` and again with the `base64encode()` function.